# Regex is malfunctioning on the coordinates data

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

I have a regex that is supposed to take out all the characters which are non numeric in the string except the space.

Input looks something like this :

`{“23 882 91 317”, “55 672 871 437”, “230 12 435 907”, “320 32 855 107”}`

Output should look like this :

`23 882 91 317 55 672 871 437 230 12 435 907 320 32 855 107`

Instead I am seeing output :

`23 882 91 317 5 672 871 437 30 12 435 907 20 32 855 107`

It is removing a numeric character right after `, "` and 
I am left with :

```
5 instead of 55
30 instead of 230
20 instead of 320
```

I am not expert at the regex so wanted to see if someone can point out  what is wrong in the code. Following is the how the regex looks like right now.

```
String processedString = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s].", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s].` needs to match exactly two characters for the replacement to happen. First character is a non-alphanumeric non-space character hence in your string they are,

```
{“23 882 91 317”, “55 672 871 437”, “230 12 435 907”, “320 32 855 107”}
^              ^  ^ and so on
```

And the next character in your regex is a `.` which will match any character. Hence your regex is removing characters in pairs, where first character is the one you intended but the second character sometimes gets luckily to be matched with the character you want to remove but sometimes the `.` matches a digit unfortunately due to which it removes the digit. See this demo for what your regex is matching.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Qy0Sk/1)**

You should change that `.` to `+` to make it remove one or more characters and use this regex,

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+
```

**[Correctly replacing only unwanted characters demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Qy0Sk/2)**

Your Java code,

```
String s = "{“23 882 91 317”, “55 672 871 437”, “230 12 435 907”, “320 32 855 107”}";
String processedString = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+", "");
System.out.println(processedString);
```

Prints the following without removing any digits,

```
23 882 91 317 55 672 871 437 230 12 435 907 320 32 855 107
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Pushpesh this was really helpful ! Got a lot of understanding in detail as to how this regex works.

Comment: Glad to hear, that my answer helped you :)